# How to print an HTML page horizontally and include data from database?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a shopping website and I want to print a shipping labels for orders.
The format of the shipping lable need to be like in the picture.[image]

which means, I have this structure, and I need to fill in 4 data fields.
The data is not the problem.
My problem is that I tried to do it, and when I pressed `ctrl+p`, I didn't have the option of printing the page horizontally.

So my question is how is it possible that I can't choose "horizontally" in the page-layout option??

If I succeed to fix this problem, it will be easier for me to do the rest, but still, I want to ask also if there is a way of writing HTML pages (pages to be print)? Because this is actually my first time that I write a page like this.

At the beginning I tried to write the text when it is rotated 90 degrees, so that when I print the page (vertically - because I can't choose another option...) it will be printed as I want it to be. I found it very difficult to write the data in its right position because I couldn't fit the data to the format (because it is 90 degrees rotated...)

Another important thing is the fact that this is not an online website, it is a website on the computer localhost (which means the URL is: "localhost/.../.../something.php"). I mention this because I have noticed that all the "localhost" pages don't have the option of printing horizontal. I don't know if it is related, it sounds very strange to me.

Does anyone have an idea why I couldn't choose "horizontal" in the printing options?
Or does anyone know what are the "rules" of HTML printing pages?